# pool processing use async memory leak

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

need some help with my code I'm trying to use pool to run some func on my list.

its a file contain a lot of data. like 71GB of text.

I'm trying go over the lines as fast as possible.
but for some reason on the middle of running, I get killed out of memory

I think its because my pool.close and pool.join is in the end of my code.

but I'm not sure how to fix it to avoid memory leak. i think my process never die and hold the data.

Note: api.delete_object(item) return a lot of data back. maybe it gets stuck somehow on memory?

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

pool_size = 8  # my "parallelness"


def worker(item):
    try:
        result = api.delete_object(item)
    except:
        print('error with item')

pool = Pool(pool_size)        
i=0
for chunk in pd.read_csv("/folder/files_to_delete",chunksize=1000,header=None):
            i+=1000
            for ind in chunk.index:
              if "something.txt" not in chunk[0][ind]:
                    pool.apply_async(worker, (chunk[0][ind],))
                    print("{}".format(i), end='\r')
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: 2 things: even when using fork it's good practice to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to guard execution. you can set `maxtasksperchild` keyword in pool constructor to re-start worker processes periodically in order to collect poorly managed resources.

Comment: how much should i set it up?
maxtasksperchild = 1 ?
will it help on the memory leak?

Comment: maxtasksperchild cant be used on TheardPool,
should i use a different processing method ? @Aaron

Comment: I missed the `ThreadPool` my bad.. maybe try [`tracemalloc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) or some other 3rd party lib to profile memory usage to find the leak?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have tagged your question with `multiprocessing`, you are using multithreading. But it seems to me that you might be better off using multiprocessing since it's not clear to me how much "parallelism" you can achieve executing `api.delete_object(item)` using threads.

Anyway, you might try rearranging your code to use function `imap_unordered` and then iterate the *iterable* it returns. Although the return values from your worker function `worker` are not particularly interesting (the worker function as posted is only returning `None`, but perhaps that is a simplification), retrieving these values should be freeing up the memory being used to hold them.

```python
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def generate_arguments():
    i = 0
    with pd.read_csv("/folder/files_to_delete",chunksize=1000,header=None) as rdr:
        for chunk in rdr:
            i += 1000
            for ind in chunk.index:
                if "something.txt" not in chunk[0][ind]:
                    yield chunk[0][ind]
                    print("{}".format(i), end='\r')
        

def worker(item):
    try:
        result = api.delete_object(item)
    except:
        print('error with item')

def main():
    pool_size = 8  # my "parallelness"
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    results = pool.imap_unordered(worker, generate_arguments())
    # You can iterate results to get return values, which are None, from worker function:
    for result in results:
        # result is return value from worker
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you do switch to multiprocessing, you should specify a *chunksize* argument on the call to `imap_unordered`. I suggest you approximate the number of tasks that will be submitted and divide by 4 * the pool size and use the result as that value. For instance, if you estimate you would be submitting 200,000 tasks and you had a pool size of 8, then use a *chunksize* value of `200_000 / (4 * 8) = 6250`.

Note that `imap_unordered` can return the results in arbitrary order but is more efficient than `imap`. If you are actually returning from `worker` something other than `None` and need the results to be in the order of task submission, then use method `imap` or have `imap_unordered` return additionally its passed argument.

Comment: wow thanks.
i tried the solution and got:
`AttributeError: __enter__`

any idea why ?

Comment: there is still memory leak :(
any idea why ?

Comment: I believe the `AttributeError` arises if you are not running at least `pandas` 1.2. So don't use  the `with` context manager and just explicitly do a `close`.

Comment: As far as your continuing memory issues, I don't know what the rest of the code might be doing to cause a leak, so my answer simply was something obvious to try.